# Taking date and time Strings from a SQLite database and setting AlarmManager

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-alarms

So, I have been trying this for a long time. I need to save the date and time as a String `(DD-MM-YYYY & HH:mm)` in a `SQLite` database.

Now I have to set up my `AlarmManager` to show notifications, but AlarmManager takes the time and date in milliseconds.

How can I convert these into milliseconds?

What is the right way to store Date and Time in a `SQLite DB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to do this:

```
   SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
   String time = "12-01-2014 10:23";

   long millis = format.parse(time).getTime();
```

This should work. I have something like this too, and I set an extra column where I save the milliseconds from this date inside the database, so I can get it directly.

Comment: This is not going to work with "12:3:2014 9:58" right ? got an IlligalArgumentException , Think I gotta do a lot of work :(

Comment: for a better understanding, You should read about SimpleDateFormat http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. If You want to parse a string like this, your SimpleDateFormat has to look like: ("DD:MM:YYYY HH:mm")

Comment: I think thats dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm

Answer (score 2):

> Which is the right way to store Date and Time in sqlite ?

You might find it easier in the end to store your dates as milliseconds in your SQLite database (using SQLite's `INTEGER` data type).  This makes it very easy to use that value for creating `Calendar` objects or for using it in creating an `AlarmManager` alarm.  But if you store the date in a String format in your database, you will probably find yourself performing String manipulation on it.

If you store your date as milliseconds in your database, it is very easy to create a Calendar object from it and extract the year, month and day:

```
// get millis from database
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(millis);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

For storing times, I find it best to store them as a 24-hour string in the "HH:MM" format.  Android's TimePickers accept and return hours in 24-hour format, so this just makes life easier.

You still need to do some minimal String manipulation to get the `int` hours and minutes from "HH:MM", but it can be as simple as:

```
String timeString = "18:30";
int hours = Integer.valueOf(timeString.split(":")[0]);
int minutes = Integer.valueOf(timeString.split(":")[1]);
```

But if you wanted to, you could even store your times in millis as a SQLite `INTEGER`, then use that value to create a new `Calendar` object and extract the hours and minutes from it:

```
// get millis from database
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTimeInMillis(millis);
int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Thanks ..Very useful informatoin . This way I could do it a lot more easier..But I'm almost done with my app...anyway Thanks for this valuable info.

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Glad I could help in some way.

Comment: can we do it with datepicker and timepicker?

Comment: TimePickerDialog accepts `int`s for hours and minutes, so you would just use the technique in my answer to translate from millis to hours and minutes, then pass those hours and minutes into the constructor.  DatePickerDialog accepts `int`s for year, month and day.  So you would use your millis to create a new `Calendar` object, then extract the year, month and day from that.  Then you could use those values to create a new DatePicker.